# Why Python 3 map function is not called when deque is used?

Tags: python-3.x, deque

The argument function of map does not be called when I use deque as input for it.

If I just loop it and call rotate function, it worked.

Why res does not rotate at all after map function?

```
>>> print(res)
[deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3]), deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3]), deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3]), deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3]), deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3])]
>>> map(lambda x: x.rotate(1), res)
<map object at 0x10a35b7f0>
>>> print(res)
[deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3]), deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3]), deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3]), deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3]), deque([4, 5, 1, 2, 3])]
```

However if I used for loop it is rotated.

```
>>> for x in res:
...     x.rotate(1)
...
>>> print(res)
[deque([3, 4, 5, 1, 2]), deque([3, 4, 5, 1, 2]), deque([3, 4, 5, 1, 2]), deque([3, 4, 5, 1, 2]), deque([3, 4, 5, 1, 2])]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` (like a generator expression) is lazy. It doesn't iterate the list and evaluate its function until you force it to, and you aren't forcing the iterator to run here.

You could force it by putting it in a list (or using a comprehension from the start):

```
list(map(lambda x: x.rotate(1), res))
```

`list` forcibly evaluates the returned `map`.

Ideally though, you shouldn't be using `map` to carry out side effects. The purpose of `map` is to transform one list into another. Just use your full `for` loop here for clarity.

Comment: Is there any other way to 'force' the map to execute? That lambda function returns 'None' and I do not need them.

Comment: @jong Any way that causes the iterator to call `next` repeatedly will work. Manually looping over the iterator using `for` or using `list` are the simplest ways. If you need to find a way to force it though, you likely shouldn't be using `map` in the first place. Again, just use `for` from the start. No need to get fancy here.